# Wrapping/facading a ScalaJS react js component (react-sticky) in the most encapsulating manner possible

Tags: javascript, scala, react-native, scala.js, scalajs-react

I have seen several methods of making a facade or wrapping Javascript components in `scala.js`, including doing so for `react.js Component`s. They seem to vary in the degree they encapsulate or hide the functionality provided by the component itself, I suppose based on their needs (maybe they only need to call one method).

In my case, I need to use a component called `react-sticky` and I am first trying to determine how to proceed with making a facade for one of its just two component classes, [`StickyContainer`, code provided here.](https://github.com/captivationsoftware/react-sticky/blob/master/src/container.js)

My questions are as follows:

1. How do I deal with `static` Javascript methods in `scala`? Do I even need to care about this, or can I be agnostic about it?
2. What is the **minimum** amount of "facade" I need to make to just include the `component` without any `Props` in another `component`'s `render()`?
3. What is fundamentally *different* about wrapping or facading a `reactjs` component as opposed to any other `js` native class?

Finally, which of the following strategies would be most appropriate?

```
@js.native
trait StickyContainer extends js.Object { ... }
object StickyContainer extends StickyContainer {}
```

or

```
case class StickyContainer(offset: js.UndefOr[Double],...) {
    def apply() = { React.createElement(ReactUniversal.Image, JSMacro[StickyContainer](this), children: _*)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I deal with static Javascript methods in scala? Do I even need to care about this, or can I be agnostic about it?

You don't need worry about underlying implementations of react components,when you want to wrap it. But in general if you want specify static fields for a class

```
 @ScalaJSDefined
 class MyComponent extends ReactComponent {
  ...
}

val ctor = js.constructorOf[MyComponent]

ctor.childContextTypes = js.Dictionary("contextfield" -> React.PropTypes.`object`.isRequired)
```

If you're wondering about out of box static fields support in scala.js ..  https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/issues/1902

> What is the minimum amount of "facade" I need to make to just include the component without any Props in another component's render()?

```
global.ReactSticky = require('react-sticky') // load js lib

@js.native
object ReactSticky extends js.Object {
  val StickyContainer : js.Dynamic = js.native
  val Sticky : js.Dynamic = js.native
}

//Using JSMacro
case class StickyContainer(fields ..) {
  def apply(children : ReactNode*) = {
     val props  = JSMacro[StickyContainer](this)
     React.createElement(ReactSticky.StickyContainer,props,children :_*) 
   }
}

//Using FunctionMacro
def StickyContainer(fields ..)(children : ReactNode*) : ReactElement = {
     val props  = FunctionMacro()
     React.createElement(ReactSticky.StickyContainer,props,children :_*) 
   }
}
```

> What is fundamentally different about wrapping or facading a reactjs component as opposed to any other js native class?

If you see `object ReactSticky extends js.Object ...` there is no difference in writing facade. but in react world you need `ReactElement`s thats where you need extra wrapper for - `React.createElement(classCtor,props,children)` call ..

Comment: thanks so much. I love sjs but it's hard to get help. Quick question: I didnt want to use `ScalaJsDefined` because it isn't , right? It's native defined...

Comment: OK real question time - how would you use do this in `japgolly` `scalajs-react` instead of `sri`?

Comment: scalajs-react doesn't support class based components .., but there is a fork with ES6 class support - https://github.com/xsistens/scalajs-react .

Comment: I kinda figured as much but i should update that I was *was* able to get it  to work with a react component using the methods they/you suggested plus some changes.

Comment: I guess I might as well switch over to SRI now before i get invested in japgolly, huh?

Answer (score 0):

Props to `invariant` for the correct answer on how to get SRI-based components working. The other `japgolly`-based ones are not as friendly in dealing with third-party JS.

Here is how I was able to get the library `react-mt-svg-lines`, an animation lib, working:

#### the clazz

```
case class MtSvgLines(
                      key: js.UndefOr[String] = js.undefined,
                      ref: js.UndefOr[String] = js.undefined,
                      animate: js.Any = true,
                      duration: Double = 10.0,
                      stagger: js.UndefOr[Double] = js.undefined,
                      timing: js.UndefOr[String] = js.undefined,
                      playback: js.UndefOr[String] = js.undefined,
                      fade: js.UndefOr[String] = js.undefined
                    )
{

  def apply(children: ReactNode*): ReactComponentU_ = {
    val props = JSMacro[MtSvgLines](this)
    val f = React.asInstanceOf[js.Dynamic].createFactory(js.Dynamic.global.SvgLines.default)
    if (children.isEmpty)
      f(props).asInstanceOf[ReactComponentU_]
    else if (children.size == 1)
      f(props, children.head).asInstanceOf[ReactComponentU_]
    else
      f(props, children.toJsArray).asInstanceOf[ReactComponentU_]
  }

}
```

Notably, make sure that the argument in `createFactory` is the `global.Whatever` you `export` to. Account for children's variances in numbers. Use `js.UndefOr` for every optional.

#### the client

```
def render(S: State, C: PropsChildren) = {
  <.header(^.key := UUID.randomUUID().toString, Styles.Header_TextIsCentered, Styles.Header_BackgroundIsGrayBlue_WithWhiteText)(
    <.div(^.className := "container")(
      <.h1()("justin shin, tampa fl"),
      MtSvgLines(animate = true, duration = 500) {
        import japgolly.scalajs.react.vdom.svg.all._

        svg(SvgStyles.svg,
          defs(
            maskTag(id := "mask", x := "0", y := "0", width := "100%", height := "100%",
              rect(id := "alpha", x := "0", y := "0", width := "100%", height := "100%"),
              text(id := "title", x := "50%",y := "0", dy := "1.58em")("Justin", transform := "translate(50, 0)"),
              text(id := "title", x := "50%",y := "0", dy := "1.58em")("Tampa")
            )
          ),
          rect(id := "base", x := "0", y := "0", width := "100%", height := "100%"),
          path(stroke := "green", strokeWidth := "10", fill := "none", d := "M20.8,51c0,0,20.8,18.2,21.5,18.2c0.6,0,33.3-38.5,33.3-38.5"),

        )
      }
    )
  )
}
```

Comment: hmm wrapper i mentioned above is not sri specific , it should work with any scala-react lib!. for some reason if scalajs-react doesn't support `React.createElement(classCtor,props,children :_*) ` then file an issue there  :)  (its official React API )

Comment: I follow you... it's the same underlying JS so it sihould work, but ...try the `react.createElement`... I could not get it to work in the example above with `scalajs-react`

Comment: ah ok, looks like they need a overloaded version which accepts javascript ctor :)

Comment: Coming from a Backbone world into angular for about 4 months and then react for 2 and now this (albeit my own choosing but still), it is tough for me to distinguish design choices from hard requirements and scalajs oddities from reactjs oddities :)

Comment: i can understand your pain,recently i also went through the similar(trying out different tech..) scenario.for my app backend first i picked graphql as service then ditched it because of inflexiblity, rolled by own scala/graphql backend now i have to host my  scala app and db(mongodb) :( . Finally i settled with cloudant for now :)